# Printing a sheet of labels in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: reporting, acumatica

Any idea how to do it?

Yes, I've reviewed the existing two reports (Both within Distribution, Inventory, Reports, Forms)
Location Labels - in619000.rpx and 
Inventory Item Labels - IN619200.rpx

Can get them to go across, that's fine.
Problem is the Vertical Spacing - Seems to be different between Chrome and IE, so by the time I get to the end of the page, it's no longer lining up with the label

Sample label is the fairly common "Avery 5160 (1” x 2 5/8”)", and I want to get all 30 on the page (3 across, 10 down).  Run the report, specify the criteria, get the preview, print through button on screen (no export to PDF) and get different paper printed between IE and Chrome - Along with wildly different print options options

I've removed all but the detail section, I've set the margins to 0 on the overall report, I've explicitly set the detail height to 1 in, and show just a single horizontal line.  Then measure distance between the line, it's not 1 inch, and also different between Chrome and IE.  Ok, I can get it the right size by trial and error, but would prefer to be browser independent, and not need to maintain a report per "Browser Group"

Answer (score 0):

You can print from PDF within the browser without having to export the PDF document:

1. Go to your report page.
2. In print and email settings, check 'Print in PDF format'
3. Provide a Template name, check 'Default' template and save the changes
   [image]

If done correctly, the report should show display in PDF by default in the browser and the toolbar will show the 'View HTML' option instead of 'View PDF':
[image]

The printing interface will vary by browser because it's using the browser or browser extension functionality to display and print PDF. In chrome this is what it looks like when you launch the report in PDF mode by default:
[image]

PDF stands for Portable Document Format, the goal of the standard is to produce documents that display and print identical in different environments (browser, OS etc..). This is exactly the problem you're trying to solve so I suggest you focus on making PDF printing work as this is the proper long term solution.

HTML on the other hand was never meant to produce similar result in different environment. Since the browser vendors can and do change their rendering stacks at any moment without notice it's futile to try to get similar results in different browsers/os. What works today could very well break in the next update.

Comment: The core issue is that HTML doesn't allow for pixel perfect rendering by design. That's why PDF gained so much traction when it comes to printing, even on the web. If you're interested in the topic here is a link: https://www.admixweb.com/please-stop-pixel-perfect-design-web-design/

Comment: The other note:  USER BEHAVIOR - Must make sure that the "just print" option is selected when trying to print the PDF, else it "helps" by re-sizing (e.g. messing up) your PDF.  If download and load in Adobe Reader (e.g. 2018.009.20050), when choose Print and get the dialog box up, in the Page Sizing & Handling, make sure it's set to "Actual Size", and not any of the scaling options (e.g. NOT Fit, Shrink oversized Pages, Custom Scale)

Comment: Can default to PDF from within the Report itself - Open report designer, choose the overall report, go to Properties, then Behavior\Common Settings\View PDF.  Set this to True rather than False, so that the check box will always default to "true".  This works even if not prompting, e.g. through a PXReportRequiredException